# Image in React Native Not Showing (stored in State)

Tags: react-native, image

I'm getting Image Url successfully from Firebase,but the problem is when I console ImageUrl it gives the correct value but when i try to use it it doesnot show at all.

Code is :

```
    setImageUrl(JSON.stringify(url))
    <Image style={styles.img} source={{uri:ImageUrl}} />
```

Tried Like this

```
    setImageUrl({uri:setImageUrl(JSON.stringify(url))})
    <Image style={styles.img} source={ImageUrl} />
```

But still does not show the ImageUrl is giving correct value with ""

Comment: Can you elaborate what `setImageUrl(string)` actually does? Does it use `useState`?

Comment: yes it is useState